# Docker environment variable not available in RUN command

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am having difficulties with ARG & ENV in docker after I have upgraded to Docker version 20.10.7, build f0df350 on windows 10.

I have made dockerfile to show issue:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime AS base

ARG node_build=production
ENV node_build_env=${node_build}

FROM node:12.18.3 AS node-build
WORKDIR /root
RUN echo $node_build_env > test.txt

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=node-build /root/test.txt ./
```

My goal here is that an ARG can be set and it will be then set as environment variable inside the container and if none is set it has a default value.

In this Dockerfile I am attempting to write the environment variable `node_build_env` to a text file then copy it to the final layer.  The problem though is that the file is empty.

To re-create these are commands I am using:

```
docker build -t testargs:test .

docker run -it --rm testargs:test /bin/bash

cat test.txt
```

The file is empty.  However if I run:

```
docker build -t testargs:test . --target node-build
```

and then manually run the command:

```
echo $node_build_env > test.txt
```

It works and the value `production` is written into the file.

Why does it work when I do it manually but not as part of the RUN command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using multi-stage builds.

Your ARG & ENV belongs to `base` stage. And you're not using your `base` stage in your `node-build` build stage.

That means there is no `node_build_env` value in `node-build`. Hence the following line creates an empty `test.txt` file.

```
RUN echo $node_build_env > test.txt
```

However your `final` stage uses `base` stage. Which means it has access to `node_build_env` variable. So after building your image using `docker build -t testargs:test .` and then open up an interactive session with that container and try to execute the following command,

```sh
echo $node_build_env
```

You will see `production` will be printed out in the terminal.

I believe this will help you solve the problem. Cheers  !!!

edit:

this is working version:

```
ARG node_build=production

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime AS base

FROM node:12.18.3 AS node-build

ARG node_build
ENV node_build_env=$node_build

WORKDIR /root
RUN echo $node_build_env > test.txt

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=node-build /root/test.txt ./
```